# Getting ENOENT error in CodeSandbox CI but not in GitHub Actions or locally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, continuous-integration, codesandbox

I'm trying to put together a [GitHub PR](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/pull/231) for the [`react-querybuilder`](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/) library, but my [CodeSandbox CI job](https://ci.codesandbox.io/status/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/pr/231/builds/184318) is failing with the following message:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile '/tmp/7f429ec0/react-querybuilder-v4.0.0-beta2.tgz' -> '/tmp/output/react-querybuilder/_pkg.tgz']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  path: '/tmp/7f429ec0/react-querybuilder-v4.0.0-beta2.tgz',
  dest: '/tmp/output/react-querybuilder/_pkg.tgz' }
```

The [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/runs/4076740585) run fine, and I can run the `npm run build` command locally without issues, so I'm not sure if I have something configured wrong or if there is a problem with CodeSandbox CI.

Answer (score 0):

[Finally figured it out](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/pull/231). When I ran the `np` command to publish `v4.0.0-beta.2`, I included the "v" in the version number parameter, i.e.:

```
npm run publish:npm -- v4.0.0-beta.2 --tag=beta
```

This should have been run like this:

```
npm run publish:npm -- 4.0.0-beta.2 --tag=beta
```

The errant "v" caused the version number in `package.json` to have a "v" prefix, which apparently confused CodeSandbox CI.

After [removing the "v" prefix in `package.json`](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/pull/231/commits/a3f837e6c17a9736a26fd643ab6181045ea9edc2), the [CI build is passing](https://ci.codesandbox.io/status/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/pr/231/builds/184773).